# Default/Overridable content for Aurelia template (template parts)

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm trying to dip my toes into the Aurelia framework. I'm trying to create a reusable pager component.

***Is there a way to provide some default content, but allow it to be overridden if the user of the component so desires?***

For instance, my pager.html looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="pager-container">
    <content select="pager-beginning"></content>
  </div>
</template>
```

my pager-beginning.html looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <content>
    <button type="button">|<</button>
  </content>
</template>
```

---

I was thinking I should be able to do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <require from="components/pager/pager"></require>
  <pager></pager>
</template>
```

and have the markup produced look like this:

```html
<div class="pager-container">
  <button type="button">|<</button>
</div>
```

or alternatively I should be able to do something like this:

```html
<template>
  <require from="components/pager/pager"></require>
  <pager>
    <pager-beginning><button type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i></button></pager-beginning>
  </pager>
</template>
```

and have the markup produced look like this:

```html
<div class="pager-container">
  <button type="button"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i></button>
</div>
```

The idea being that I could provide all of the functionality of a pager, all of the logic specific to a pager in my pager.js file and a default html rendering, but then allow the user of the component to override pieces of the html if they so desired.

---

What currently seems to be happening is that the markup inside of the pager-beginning.html `<content></content>` tag is always getting replaced. So I get markup rendered that looks like this:

```html
<div class="pager-container"></div>
```

I can't figure out how to provide it with that 'default' content functionality.

Comment: Please note that the `<content>` tag has been replaced by the `<slot>` tag in version 1 of Aurelia, in accordance with the latest changes to the Shadow DOM specification.  [Aurelia documenation](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/templating/latest/templating-content-projection) and corresponding [blog post](http://blog.aurelia.io/2016/05/23/aurelia-shadow-dom-v1-slots-prerelease/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "template parts" feature.  More info [here](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/latest/doc/article/cheat-sheet) (search for "template parts").

**pager.html**

```html
<template>
  <div class="pager-container">
    <button type="button" click.delegate="gotoBeginning()">
      <template replaceable part="goto-beginning-button-content">|<</template>
    </button>
  </div>
</template>
```

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./components/pager/pager"></require>
  <pager>
    <template replace-part="goto-beginning-button-content">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></i>
    </template>
  </pager>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I love the new docs, but am still having trouble finding what I want there. This really helped.